# simple onclick in js already added in application.js doesnt executes- rails 3.2.19 and ruby 2.0

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

i know this is very immature question to ask but recently i added a simple `onclick` method in my `users.js` file already added to `application.js`.Now as far as i know..all the `js` is available to me in a single `application.js`(as i can see it from firefox),that means every code in application should be executable on demand but after i added:-

users.js inside document.ready

```
//add loading gif on saving
$(".nposting").click(function(){
  console.log("im ready");
  $(this).html("<i>Posting...</i><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x' style='padding-left: 5px'></i>")
 });
```

---

```
####application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require users
//= require bootstrap
```

---

```
   #####included in my layout file at the bottom of page..
       <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

---

```
#####so why its not working on my view file:-
###removed unrelevant part of file
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default video_tags_badge nposting">Post and Share</button>
      </div>
```

so..i have everything..but why code for `nposting.click` not working.i really dont want to go for page specific loading for scripts...this should work..i confirmed my `users.js` is loading as well using `console.log` but why the code inside is not triggering....still working because it works inside the view but not after including `application.js`.As far as i know..code is present but why its not working...do i need to include `user.js` in view file(i dont think so)???

Comment: You have listed some things you can experiment with, but you have not tried them yet. Please at least try page specific loading, or including in the view file, to see if it at least offers clues to what has gone wrong with your asset pipeline. Also what is your browser's debugger telling you about what happens after document.ready?

Comment: all js in manifest are loading..it means that i have the js with me on every page which i can use...then it should work...well @dcorking thanks for other options ,yes i can try it soon but why this is not working?

Comment: Has the click callback been added?

Comment: yes..its already added to users.js and users.js is included in manifest file

Comment: Has it been added to the event? (If you evaluate the event or open an inspector on it.)

Comment: yes..as i said..i can see the log in document.load ...i have the code in application.js minified version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution...as **i dont want** to load/include my application with multiple js with the number of controllers and put `<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>`....so i just made a common.js and included it in the required view files .....what i understood...

1. using `application.js` ,you get all your js in one request which `improves your performanc`e also removing `require tree` and adding only required js files helps.
2. once you have all your js files available..you can use it just by including it in your `views`.

now its working without adding extra code and just adding `<%= javascript_include_tag "users" %>` in my required view files